# Logical Disk size using python

Tags: python

Below code i wrote to get the logical disk size.

```
import wmi
import shutil
connection = wmi.connect_server(server="", user="", password="")
c = wmi.WMI(wmi=connection)

    for logical_disk in partition.associators ("Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition"):
        Disk_Caption = logical_disk.Caption
        print(Disk_Caption)
        total, used, free = shutil.disk_usage("\\")
        print("Total: %d GB" % (total // (2 ** 30)))
        print("Used: %d GB" % (used // (2 ** 30)))
        print("Free: %d GB" % (free // (2 ** 30)))
```

I have C:and D: but in output for both C: and D: it is giving the size of C: itself.

Can you please let me know what i am doing wrong here

Comment: You are calling `shutil.disk_usage()` with exactly the same parameter each time, how could it possibly do anything other than give you the same results over and over?

Comment: Then what change i have to make...??